# What font type is being used on this logo?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

Im re-building a project for a new client and I know I've seen this font before but cannot see to locate it and the font finder services are not having much luck either.

Does anyone know what it might be?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ILM is correct that it’s Avant Garde.

More specifically, it’s *based on* [ITC’s version of ITC Avant Garde](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/avant-garde-gothic/).<sup>1</sup> The square dot on the i, the tripartite lowercase k, and the very coiling shape of the s are dead giveaways:

[image]

However, the f, a, and n have been manually modified to remove the part of the [cross stroke](http://www.typographydeconstructed.com/cross-stroke/) that extends beyond the stem on the left side. That is not part of the font; it was probably done in Illustrator, to lend a bit of a [Bauhaus](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/bauhaus/)ian look to the logo (note, though, that Bauhaus’ a is open at the bottom, unlike in this modified Avant Garde logo):

[image]

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Confusingly, Adobe has also made a version of ITC Avant Garde, but this is ITC’s own version.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Avante garde??? Now that's going to bug me :)

Comment: [Be kind, show a preview of the font please.](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/be-kind-show-a-preview-of-the-font)